Change brush size increment with [ ] short cuts? Finer control of brush size shortcut
Using the brush tool, when I want to increment or decrement the size of the brush I can use the shortcut [and ] to increase and decrease the size of the brush.
At smaller brush sizes (1-10 px) it will increase 1 px at a time (per press of ]). Between 10-50 px, it will increase 5 px per press, between 50-100 px 10 px per press, between 50-100 px, 10 px per press, etc.
The problem is that I'm working with a very high resolution / ppi image and I'd like finer-grained control of this shortcut. For example, only increase 5 px per press regardless of brush size. I have to rapidly toggle between variably sized circles that I'm filling in and would like to do it with shortcuts.
Is there a way to change this or a good workaround? Thank you!

Photoshop has an alternate shortcut that may address your needs.



Shortcut
macOS
Windows




Adjust brush size
Control + Option + Left-click + drag horizontally
Alt + Right-click + drag horizontally


Adjust brush hardness
Control + Option + Left-click + drag vertically
Alt + Right-click + drag vertically



This shortcut adjusts the brush size at a linear rate based on your current zoom level. It pairs nicely with the following commands.



Shortcut
macOS
Windows




Zoom
z + Left-click + drag horizontally
z + Left-click + drag horizontally


Pan
Spacebar + Left-click + drag
Spacebar + Left-click + drag


Rotate view
r + Left-click + drag
Spacebar + Left-click + drag



Using these shortcuts together allows you to keep your dominant hand on the mouse and your other hand on the keyboard. They are also ideal when using a stylus.
